# Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: io.jsonwebtoken in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Tags: deployment, microservices, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to add explicit dependencies to a deployment using
the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in my maven module.
But I am not getting the io.jsonwebtoken dependency at runtime.

My pom.xml entries

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
         <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
         <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <version>13.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml entries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="org.infinispan" export="true"/>
           <module name="io.jsonwebtoken" optional="false"/>
           <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core-public" export="true"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.logging" export="true"/>
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am getting the following error when I am trying to create a
jar out of my code use that jar in another service.

```
    06:07:21,356 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management- 
   operation] (Controller Boot 
    Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: 
    ([("deployment" => 
    "keycloak-event-listener-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")]) - failure 
    description: {"WFLYCTL0080: 
    Failed services" => 
    {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.keycloak-event-listener- 
   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load 
    module: 
    deployment.keycloak-event-listener-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: 
    io.jsonwebtoken"}}
```

I tried manifest file also but got the same error only for
io.jsonwebtoken dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is referencing "deployment.keycloak-event-listener-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" module on Wildfly application server and in turn this same module depends on the "io.jsonwebtoken" module which its not available on Wildfly application server or is not being referenced in the "module.xml" file.
If you need more help just let me know.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me some links for reference about how to add module in wildfly application server

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7/